# Ethernet close after a while when connecting to another computer

Tags: networking, networkmanager

I connected directly my Linux machine with another computer then start copying files.
However, it disconnects after a while that I have to navigate into settings to turn it on again.

**Note:**
I am not familiar with Linux networking, if you need any more information, feel free to ask.

Distro: Arch Linux

NetworkManager: 1.40.2-1